# error 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have added follow action to get products accroding to cat.id.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnlineHome(string CategoryId)
{
  OnlineDataModel dm = new OnlineDataModel();
  dm.CatagoryData = new List<category>();
  dm.ProductData = new List<product>();
  dm.CatagoryData = db.categories.ToList();
  //dm.ProductData = (from p in db.products where p.CategoryID == Convert.ToInt32(CategoryId) select p).ToList() ;
  var data= db.products.Where(d => d.CategoryID == Convert.ToInt32(CategoryId)).ToList();
  return View(dm);
}
```

I am getting following error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and >this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

need a solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried Int32.Parse() instead?

Comment: Convert the value to an int then pass that value to the expression. But why not just make the parameter `int` rather that string so you don't need to do any conversion (the `DefaultModelBiner` will do it for you)

Comment: Thank you stephen for your help. It works. Why it doesn't work if I convert it to int32 in the expression.

Comment: The query has to be able to be converted an actual SQL statement but C# method cant be converted to SQL

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1:

Try to declare you Integer variable first:

```
int iCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryId);
```

Then update your code to:

```
var data= db.products.Where(d => d.CategoryID == iCategoryId).ToList();
```

Solution 2 (recommended):

Make sure your action receives an integer and modify the type of the variable:

```
public ActionResult OnlineHome(int CategoryId)
```

Then update your code the same way to:

```
var data = db.products.Where(d => d.CategoryID == CategoryId).ToList();
```

Feel free to add your own cast validations to both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
  int catId = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryId);
  var data = db.products.Where(d => d.CategoryID == catId).ToList();
```